# PHP, if session is started redirect to a different page

Tags: php, session, redirect

```
<?php 
1.
 if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
header('Location: log.php');
}

2.
 if (session_id() != '') {
    header('Location: log.php');
}
3.
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    header("Location: log.php");
    exit;
}

4.
 if (session_status() != PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    header("Location: log.php");
}

?>
```

I want my php to redirect to from main.php to log.php if the session is live. I want to achieve an effect where logged on users cannot access a page and once they try to do it via a url they get automatically redirected to a different page.
Above are the attempts I did and did not work for me.

Comment: I think you forgot to use (or mention) `session_start();`

Comment: Did you make sure to use `session_start()`? There will never be a session in any subsequent pages as long as `session_start` hasn't been declared. Use the presence of `$_SESSION` variables in combination with a previously declared `session_start` to take care of this properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `session_start`.

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header("Location: log.php");
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you miss the call to php session_start().
Try this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) { header('Location: log.php'); }
?>
```

And be sure that your use logged account.

Answer (score 0):

although it's 4 years later,I solve this problem just now.

Please make sure all these matter:
1. All the pages have to set the below parameter in the beginning
 if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {session_start();}

2. Adding the session variable must use $_SESSION in order to set the session as globally
3. exit(); must be added after header("location: $URL ");